# What is UX localization?

Tags: ux-field, localization

What is *UX localization* and *UX localization role*?

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen that term before but "UX localization" sounds like it's about adapting graphical user interfaces to different markets and languages. Most likely the role would focus on translations but would also need to handle the different formats for dates, currencies, numbers etc.

Wikipedia has a page on [internationalization and localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) with more general information.

Comment: This would likely not just be around language and translations, but around fitting a user experience correctly to the culture and different audiences. That might include different personas, different ethnographic research. Not the same product for all, but really researching different needs, pain points, expectations from these cultures.

Comment: I think another big part of this would be adapting for both LTR and RTL displays.

Answer (score 0):

Localization is more than just translating the UI. It also takes cultural differences into account. There is an interesting article on this topic, which explains this quite comprehensively: [Liu, Modify Your Design for Global Audiences: Crosscultural UX Design](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/crosscultural-design/).
In summary it tells:“Crosscultural design adaptations range from translation to localization. Researching general and contextual cultural differences helps you decide what type of design changes you should make.“ and explains this by example of shopping sites for Western and Chinese audiences.

Comment: can you add a extract of the article?

Comment: Okay, thanks for your hint. I added this.